# Relocate a part of a vector

Tags: c++, vector, std

I'd like to take out a range from a `vector` (remove the items) and insert them in the same order in the same vector, but at an other location.

**Example:**

```
                  0 1 2 3 4 5
Original vector:  A B C D E F
```

Take range `1-3` and insert at (after) `4`.

```
                  0 1 2 3 4 5
Resulting vector: A E B C D F
```

I could probably do this with `for` loops, or using [`remove_copy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove_copy/) and [`insert`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/insert/). Is there a better/faster way? What I don't like with `remove_copy` is that I have to specify a `value` that should *not* be removed. I want to move all of them and I'm not sure I can specify a `value` that never occurs in the `vector`.

Comment: Is this "other location" into the same vector (but a different place), or not?

Comment: @Cornstalks Yes, sorry, I forgot to say that. I updated my question. If it was separate vectors, I think it could be done with [`copy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want [`std::rotate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate):

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

//                           |<---------->|<->|          <-- rotate this range
std::vector<char> v = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' };

std::rotate(v.begin() + 1, v.begin() + 4, v.begin() + 5);
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize `rotate` would do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::copy_backward` for copying the objects (copy, not move), and then use `std::vector::erase` to remove the original objects.

For your example:

```
std::copy_backward(v.begin()+1, v.begin()+3, v.begin()+4);
v.erase(v.begin()+1, v.begin()+3);
```